# C# FTP File Integrity Check

Tags: c#, ftp

how do we know if the file downloaded from FTP is not corrupt? The FTP server does not provide any checksums of their files or is there a checksum command? Any other ways of checking downloaded file's integrity? Thanks.

Comment: Also, how do we know if a certain file is ready for downloading?

Answer (score 0):

Other than checking to see if the file will actually open in the target application or if it's missing an EOF marker or something like that, it's going to be tough to validate the contents of a downloaded file without some image or checksum to compare it to.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, using an MD5 File Verification Service (custom) of course would enable you to schedule a service in a selected repository to verify files to their md5 signatures...

Generally, this is done on the download rather than on uploads...but, ya know you may be able to figure out a way to do this for uploads.